# What is the "Value" output of Survreg in R?

Tags: r, survival, interpretation

I am exploring the use of the `survreg` function in R to analyze my current experiment.

Does anyone know what the "Value" column in the output of the function stands for?

Comment: If you mean the column headed "Value" as returned by a call to `summary`, then it is *a priori* a regression coefficient (for your survival model). Its interpretation depends on the fitted distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value column simply gives the values for the coefficient estimates.

Comment: @user1806 This is basically what I answered in my comment. Now, the point is that the OP want to know how it reads in plain english, which depends *a priori* of the kind of parametric assumptions that are made in the model.

Comment: @chi Thanks very much for the interpretation. That makes sense.